# Android - Appending text lines. Help choose the right control

Tags: android

Folks,

In my social networking application, single-line messages come from various users. As the message comes in, I need to display them in our UI as a single line that shows the time, the user, and the message line. All 3 fields need to be colored differently.

I tried to use TextView but am running into a problem. As I need various colors, I thought of using SpannableString but the problem is that TextView.Append does not support SpannableString as a parameter.

The other thought I had was to build html style text as each line comes in.

I am wondering if I am overlooking something. Perhaps there is a better user control or a better way to achieve my objective.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Well you could just *not* use `append()`... spans seem like a good approach, but apparently the performance can [be bad in some cases](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2013/09/17/android-performance-bits-and-pieces-part-i-measure-everything.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) and with help of `<font color><font/>` tag, you can set single text with different color@

```
 String result="<font color=color_code>First Textview</font> <font color=color_code>Second Textview</font><font color=color_code>Third TextView</font>";

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use three different text fields, nest them in a table layout using columns, or a relative layout. That way they will automatically resize no matter what length.

You can also use the `android:weight` tag to control how much room each one takes up.

The reason is that usually its 1 label per field in data structure. As per MVC software design pattern.